# how to select the appropriate model from the table using python codes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, model

I have the following table

```
Mdl_nm       Train_acc    Test_acc    difference in (%)
GLM           0.845056    0.858996    1.649499
RF            0.876157    0.893556    1.985884
XGB           0.871356    0.885981    1.678425
```

I want to write python pandas code that picks up the appropriate model from the table shown

The codes must pick :

1. the highest test_acc
2. The the closest train_acc and test_acc for example in the above table RF has the highest test_acc but when compared with RF train_acc the difference is 1.985884 which is higher. when we consider XGB it has the 2nd highest test_acc, when compared with the XGB train_acc the difference is 1.678425 which is lower when compared with RF.

so, in the above example even though RF has the highest testing_auc I want the codes to pick up XGB based on the 2nd condition

```
expected result : mdl_nm = XGB
```

This is the code that I have

```
mdl_nm = (df[df['Test_acc'] == df['Test_accc'].max()]['mdl_nm'].reset_index(drop=True)[0])
```

The code is returning the highest auc (1st condition) mdl_nm = `RF` however, I also want the 2nd condition to be satisfied.

is there a way that i can achieve this ? kindly help

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question.  DataFrame method `sort_values` can help.

Comment: I have added the codes I was able to satisfy the first condition but not the 2nd how can i satisfy both ?

Comment: According to the description the second condition is more important so you can rewrite your code to filter rows with minimum difference first and in the filtered rows find the maximum accuracy (applying your original code again on the filtered rows).

Comment: can you please share the codes to filter out minimum rows because the values are dynamic and keeps changing in the table

Comment: Based on your code this is just `min_diff = df[df['difference in (%)'] == df['difference in (%)'].min()]`

Comment: IF i use this condition I am getting GLM as the answer but I want XGB as the answer

Comment: The problem is that your two conditions select different models anyway. So you have to rephrase them before they can be written as code. First can be rewritten e. g. to something like: `test_acc` must be at least 98% of its maximum value. Or you can calculate a quality value with a formula using accuracy and difference and select the model with maximum quality.

Comment: Based on your conditions, would you not then compare `XGB` with the `GLM` model which has lower `Test_acc`, but also lower `difference in (%)` and prefer GLM to both?  Or do you only want to compare the next highest `Test_acc`?

Comment: when i go for the lowest Test_acc the codes are picking up only  only GLM not XGB hence after applying the filter only one row (GLM) is returning @Rawson